# Verifying many to many relationships using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have 2 tables like so:

```
 Users
 user_id (pk)
 email
 name
 inGroups (many to many relationship with groups)

 Groups
 group_id (pk)
 group_name
 whoseUsers (many to many relationship with users)
```

I have my core data code as so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@ AND inGroups = %@", user_id, group_id];
```

When this is run I get an exception thrown:

```
@"to-many key not allowed here"
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find users with a given `user_id` that are members of a group with the given `group_id`,
use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@ AND ANY inGroups.group_id = %@",
                                   user_id, group_id];
```

Comment: How do I update a piece of data in the group from the user I get back?

Comment: Like lets say I have like isActive in the groups table in which I have code like so NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; and I loop through the array but how do I update isActive?

Comment: @chris: You update an attribute by setting a new value (and save the managed object context). If this does not help I would suggest that you post a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use = use == Like this "user_id == %@ AND inGroups == %@" Second of all if it's many to many relationship then it is an NSSet. and what you are trying to do here is compare a NSSet relationship to a group_id from groups. 
EDIT you should do something like this 
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id == %@ AND inGroups CONTAINS %@", user_id, group];

Where group is the actuall Groups object

Comment: So how do I compare it to an NSSet?

Comment: Both `=` and `==` are documented and allowed in a predicate, there is no difference at all.

Comment: Why should one not use `=`? It is a predicate not Objective-C code.